# Create user data folder locally during set up

Tags: python, settings

When installing a python package, is it possible (/advisable?) to create a user data folder in their local documents folder?

I appreciate that data files can be bundled in a site packages directory during a package install (as defined by setup.py), but I'm creating a package to save human readable files, which would be more accessible in a local documents folder than in the python site packages location.

Once created, can this folder path then be saved globally for access by the package in the future?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why not create it on the first use? If you document it, this won't be a surprise. But creating a directory before I actually use a package - that would be surprising behaviour for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is a better suggestion! I guess I can save a config.ini file in the site packages folder which then points to this folder.